# Laravel localization multiline

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-localization

I have a question. I want to localize a multi line text in laravel, in file content.php from /lang/en. The proble is that if i break the text in lines(so that my code looks more readable) i get error 419. My code would look like this:

```
<?php
    return [
        'myLocalization' = "My text is 
                            on multiple lines"
    ];
?>
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of your array. Can you post the entire error you get? This will provide more information.

Comment: I have the ; at the end of the array. I just wrote this by hand, cause i can't give you details of my project. I get blank page and text "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again. " instead of the popup that i want with the message from localisations.

Answer (score 0):

Array construct requires `=>` not `=`

```
<?php
return [
    'myLocalization' => "My text is 
                         on multiple lines"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br>` tag

```
<?php
    return [
        'myLocalization' = "My text is <br>
                            on multiple lines"
    ];
?>
```

Or in one line

```
<?php 
    return [
        'myLocalization' = "My text is <br>on multiple lines"
    ];
?>
```